# Unable to run VUGEN script from UFT API test

Tags: hp-uft, vugen, uft-api

I am using "Call Virtual User Generator Script" option from Toolbox in UFT API test to call a VUGEN script. The VUGEN script is a Java over HTTP protocol script. This VUGEN script job is to publish a message on to SSL topic. When I run the script from VUGEN its working fine and publishing the message on to the topic but when I call it from UFT the script is passing saying "Successfully Executed Vugen Script" but the message is not published on to the topic. 
I am not sure if I am missing anything here. I am not sure why the message is not publishing. How can I confirm whether UFT is even calling the VUGEN script?
I am not familiar with the custom code. If anyone knows how to track this then please let me know. Any help/idea/suggestion is helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the logs from Output window...?

Comment: Here is the output log from UFT. I named the VUGEN script as Publish message to Topic.
Start
Step 'Start' : Step 'Start' started
Step 'Start' ended successfully
Step 'Test Flow' : Step 'Test Flow' started
Step 'Iteration 1' : Step 'Iteration 1' started
Step 'Publish message to Topic' : Step 'Publish message to Topic' started
Step 'Publish message to Topic' ended successfully
Step 'Iteration 1' ended successfully
Step 'Test Flow' ended successfully
Step 'End' : Step 'End' started
Step 'End' ended successfully
End

Comment: Looks like console output is not going to help...